# Do postdocs have reasonable chances to acquire non-federal funding in the US?

Tags: funding, united-states, postdocs, assistant-professor, associate-professor

[This article](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/03/data-check-us-government-share-basic-research-funding-falls-below-50) argues that the portion of federal funding is decreasing more and more in the US while funding by corporate and philantropical sources is increasing within the last decade.

[image]

I'm wondering if this shift/drift, which looks quite significant in the chart to me, means a much worse likelihood of success for postdocs trying to acquire funding, due to the fact that most postdocs have no reputation/infrastructure (offices, labs, staff,...) and are unlikely to be chosen/visible by/to corporate/philantropical sources.

Is the situation as I imagine it myself or did maybe postdocs never had high likelihood of federal funding in the US (which would be very different to europe) and the competition is not increasing drastically with less federal funding. I would like to see some numbers/statistics, no common sense/experience arguing. I hope there are maybe also statistics how much funding assistant, associate, full professors acquire and how this has changed over time.

EDIT: Independently from the discussion in the comments about postdoc/assistant professor definition, to me the answer/insight is if the drift from federal to corporate/philantropical funding is siginificantly reducing the chances of PhD's, assistant professors to acquire funding and most of the non-federal funding goes to universities/full professors? Any statistics/experience would be interesting here to me.

Comment: I’m not sure if post-docs, as individuals, ever had a large share of any of that funding. Usually post-doc funding comes as parts of larger grants. Sure, there are some programs for post-doc fellowships, but those have never been all that large.

Comment: @JonCuster Ok, which sounds very different to europe where you can get funded for some years with own staff as a PI after having a PhD. But I also suspect for assistand/associate professors in the US this shift is quite "perceptible" and making them more dependent...

Comment: Who are you defining as a post-doc? The people I think of as post-docs in the US are people who have jobs as post-docs. It doesn't make much sense to think about what funding they have access to (unless you consider fellowships specifically, which are different), because they have their position and are a post-doc specifically because that funding exists. There's no such thing as a post-doc without an office/lab because they are indeed hired to a position in an office/lab or sometimes as an instructor/lecturer.

Comment: @BryanKrause minimum definition in germany: Everyone with PhD hired by university or public research-institution, but no tenure. I think even Jun-Prof. in germany are counted as post-docs, as long no tenure. Not sure about US assistant professors, afaik still under evaluation for tenure (?)

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt Your post is tagged US; I don't think anyone would call assistant professors "post docs" here in the US, although in mathematics in particular, which is overrepresented at Academia.SE I would say, they have a bit of a peculiar system where indeed an assistant professor in math might be thought of more like a post-doc.

Comment: @BryanKrause isn't the vast majority of postdocs in the US like in europe without a assistant professor position, but still allowed to submit funding proposals as PI?

Comment: Remember that the US had a serious recession starting in about 2008, from which we recovered slowly. There were serious attempts _not_ to solve the crisis for political reasons. I'll guess that accounts for the drop off at about that time.

Comment: I'd say that the European and US definitions are generally not compatible. A US assistant professor is not considered a post-doc in any way. And, there are a variety of grant programs specifically for new professors from a wide range of funding sources.

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt - Post-docs generally are not considered as a PI on a proposal (except post-doc specific fellowships). It is an inherently temporary position as a stepping stone to a permanent position.

Comment: @JonCuster I know and this is IMO not different to europe, that's exactly the point of this question to understand if the necessary money you need for such a temporary position is harder to acquire. Federal funding in germany has the point to get a PhD graduate his own funding at a chair of a professor (the prof will not be PI). And in US you also don't become assistant professor shortly after earning your PhD, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I'd say a post-doc in the US is more like a "more independent graduate student" than a "less independent assistant professor" - like graduate students, there are opportunities for independent funding, but independent funding is not the norm (independent meaning not coming through a more senior professor-track PI).

Comment: @BryanKrause so you say in US, before you are full professor, there is no real chance to acquire funding as a PI for a 3-5 year project?! Weird, standard in germany, the DFG (analog NSF) offers you to apply for such projects with a PhD, a professor/chair hosting your project is not more than a mentor in the best case, I have seen projects up to 2 mn € volume granted to postdocs themselves being not even within tenure-track. Funny, then non-federal funding is maybe the only source to independent postdocs/PI (which don't rely on a senior prof) and increasing. Also an answer, but hard to believe.

Comment: The entry level tenure-track professor position in the US is an "assistant professor" who applies for grants as a PI. Their source of initial funding depends on field; in my field, it is common that these professors are given startup funds which typically come from university research slush funds (aka, the 'overhead' costs they charge on top of grants) one way or another. Federal granting agencies like NIH also often have easier path routes for early career faculty. They could also collaborate on existing grants, or may be applying for funds at the same time they are hired.

Comment: An "associate professor" has tenure, typically ~5 years after starting as an assistant professor. A "full professor" has been in a professor-level position for a long time, maybe 15-20 years.

Comment: Universities can grant PI status to non-tenure track faculty and they can apply for the same grants as professors, but they need to show they have the skills and resources to be a PI on the project...which are roughly the same overlapping qualifications to be a tenure track professor.

Comment: @BryanKrause  Sounds then like only PhDs who were offered assistant professor position carry on with academic career, this disturbs me, because in germany PhD who don't get tenure-track offered can and do often still come up with a very good research idea and acquire funding and get professorship offered after a successful managing of that project. But we also don't have here 50-100% overheads, in general 20%. Last question, what is roughly the ratio of PhDs to assistant professors in US academia? How long PhDs try to become assistant prof after PhD graduation before movin industry?

Comment: I think tenure track in Germany is a lot harder to get than in the US, though I might be wrong. The way US treats tenure is that if you are deserving of a long-term role in academia you are deserving of a shot at tenure; there is a very limited non-tenure pipeline (which, incidentally, is the one I am on :) ). The % of overhead means nothing, really. Money is fungible.

Comment: PhD to professor ratio is massively dependent on field. My field is new and used to be growing massively; almost everyone who got a PhD in my field 30 years ago is now a professor. Otherwise, the ratio is approximately 1 student for each professor will become a professor. I.e., natural replacement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91383/discussion-between-bryan-krause-and-michael-schmidt).